# Summing a multi-dimension crossfilter to reduce the number of dimensions

Tags: svg, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working wtih @tillandsia on [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993394/group-by-multiple-dimensions-recursively-in-dc-js/) and have made some strides thanks to @Gordon's advice. I've reshaped the data so there are Date, Hair Color, Age Group, and Value columns. E.g.

```
Date, Hair Color, Age Group, Value
1/1/21, Brown, 0-18, 10
1/1/21, Brown, 19-39, 20
1/1/21, Brown, 40+, 30
1/1/21, Blonde, 0-18, 11
1/1/21, Blonde, 19-39, 21
1/1/21, Blonde, 40+, 31
1/2/21, Brown, 0-18, 8
...
```

I've also created a fake cumulative group to sum by `Hair Color`. If I create a dimension, group, and chart like this:

```
dateColorDimension = cf.dimension([d.Date, d['Hair Color']]);
dateColorGroup = dateColorDimension.group().reduceSum(d => +d.Value);
chart
  .dimension(dateColorDimension)
  .group(dateColorGroup)
  .seriesAccessor(d => d.key[1])
  .keyAccessor(d => d.key[0])
  .valueAccessor(d => +d.value)
```

Then it looks mostly correct. Chart with only date and hair color in the dimension:
[image: Chart with only date and hair color in the dimension]

But if I tried to add the `Age Group` to the dimension like this:

```
dateColorDimension = cf.dimension([d.Date, d['Hair Color'], d['Age Group']]);
```

Then the chart has this jagged look. Chart with age group added to the dimension:
[image: Chart with age group added to the dimension]

I can see in the group that there are multiple age groups for each `Hair Color` for each date. So the accumulator is creating little vertical steps on each date as it accumulates the `Age Groups`. Is there a way that I can collapse the `Age Group` part of the group before I plot it? By collapse, I mean I would like to sum in this case. I assume I would want to keep the `Age Group` column in the dimension so that it is accessible when we do filtering for a particular `Hair Color`.

I've created a jsfiddle to better illustrate the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/djacu2/Lwp2cs9u/112/

Comment: You don’t say why you are adding the Age Group to this dimension. I would think that you want to create another date/age dimension for displaying the Age Group chart. Unless you really want to group by both columns in one chart.

Comment: Update: I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/kfvy92n6/8/) demonstrating what I talked about in the previous answer, date/color and date/age dimensions & groups. However I didn't implement filtering, and if you try to select with the brush, it exhibits a weird bug where the other chart keeps refreshing and sinks to zero. I don't have time atm to debug this, but I thought I would just ping you. If you want to try another library, I think Vega Lite can do this kind of scenario nicely. I hope to return with an answer soon (or anyone else is welcome to complete this).